# Facebox, hide url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently using jQuery based facebox:

http://defunkt.io/facebox/

Here is my link:

```
<a href="/me/edit_profile_details" rel="facebox" rev="iframe|400|600">
```

However, I am trying to hide the actual url so the href="#" rather than what it is currently. I was wondering how I can go about doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a link, but not show the url then the only way is with javascript. You can create an onclick event like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='http://www.hi.com/'; return false;">my link</a>
```